Manager isn't available in django
My Register view is like below.
class UserRegisterView( FormView ):
    template_name = 'register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')  # name of URL     

    def form_valid( self, form ):
        user = form.save()
        if user is not None:
            login( self.request, user )
        return super( UserRegisterView, self ).form_valid( form )
    
    def get( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('register')
        return super( UserRegisterView, self ).get( *args, **kwargs )

My model is like below.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )

    USER_TYPE = (
        ('S', 'Super Admin'),
        ('A', 'Admin'),
        ('P', 'Patient'),
        ('D', 'Doctor'),
        ('U', 'User'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPE)
    username = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

I am getting error Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'hospital.User'

I checked this post and applied the solution but I am getting same error again.
Here is the full traceback.
AttributeError at /register/

Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'hospital.User'
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version:     5.0.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:
Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'hospital.User'
Exception Location:     /home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py, line 196, in get
Raised during:  hospital.views.UserRegisterView
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     3.10.12
Python Path:
['/home/foysal/Documents/pYtHoN/hospital_management',
'/usr/lib/python310.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.10',
'/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
'/home/foysal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 14 May 2024 06:52:53 +0000

Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

UserCreationForm points to the builtin user model, you have to customize /  inherit from that form. See for example this answer in the duplicate

Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat. I checked the post before but I have no forms.py. What should I do ?

You're using form_class = UserCreationForm as I mentioned that form uses the builtin user model, you'll have to customize that to use your model. If you don't have a forms.py (In fact you can name this file whatever you want, its just convention to name it like that) file just make one and create your form in there.
